# Change a text file in random access

Tags: c++, text, random, binary

I have a text file and want to change it in some places, for example in byte range 4030 to 4060, in this way:

- if there is a character 'C' or 'c' followed by 'G' or 'g' ,must be changed in 'B' character

The input file is a text file and I want to get a changed text output file.  There is no random access in text file and so I must open file in binary form and make changes, but the output file will be binary and I don't have any idea to get a text output. The code is below:

```
int main()
{
    string str, cstr;
    ReadTextFile("in", 4030, 4060);
    return 0;
}

string ReadTextFile(string path, int from, int to)
{
    fstream fp(path.c_str(), ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    char *target;
    string res, str;
    target = new char[to - from + 1];
    if (!target)
    {
        cout << "Cannot allocate memory." << endl;
        return "";
    }
    fp.seekg(from);
    fp.read(target, to - from);
    target[to - from] = 0;
    res = target;
    str = changestring(res);
    fp.seekg(from);
    fp.write((char *)&str, to-from);
    return res;
}

string changestring(string str)
{
    int l = str.length();
    l = l-1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= l; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == 'C' ||  str[i] == 'c')
        {
            int j = i+1;
            if (str[j] == 'G' || str[j] == 'g')
                str[i] = 'B';
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: This isn't all the code. I assume there are prototypes made available to `main()` for the functions that follow it, otherwise none of this would compile in the first place.

Comment: On Unix, there is no distinction between a binary file and a text file and you would be able to open it as either and get it to work.  If you're on other systems and you open the file as a 'text' file, then CRLF is mapped to NL on input and back again on output, which then means you have to worry about what the byte range means.

Comment: Is the transform such that CG is mapped to BG?  Or is CG mapped to B?  There's a massive difference because the first is length preserving but the second is not.

Comment: Amongst the many problems with this, if the *last* character in the string passed to `changestring()` is a `'c'` or `'C'` your code block subsequently indexes one slot beyond the string end and into the realm of undefined behavior. (and thank you Jonathan for the reformat; I can once-again open my eyes).

Comment: None of this comments solve this problem,Please notice ,i can't get the changed text file in text format ,it is the problem.for example,one of my output is like this  AAAAAAAAAAAA(c\E0\00\00\00\00\00X\CCCgCGtcCTCCGGAAAAA ,it was a string that must be changed but now i have a text and binary form tgether.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand text and binary. It's not true that if you open a file in binary mode then the output will be binary. All binary mode does in practice is stop \n being translated to \r\n on Windows systems. In other words it affects the line endings in a text file, nothing else.

You are getting binary in your output because you are writing the pointers internal to a string to your output, write characters to your file instead.

Change

```
fp.write((char *)&str, to-from);
```

to

```
fp.write(str.c_str(), to-from);
```

This would also work

```
fp << str;
```

To get text output, write text. It doesn't matter whether you do that with `write` or with `<<`, text is just text. Stop thinking in terms of two modes of output, binary and text, it's not accurate, its *what* you write not *how* you write it that determines whether the output is text or binary.